# Joining datatables dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, datatable

Im struggling with a following issue:

I have a datatable that contains information retrieved from an SQL Server database. The information retrieved is regarding the price of certain products. So, for example, the datatable has the price of a specific product on an specific price list. One product may be present in several different price list, and today on the datatable, each combination is a different row. For example:

[image]

I need to transform the datatable into a datatable that only has one row per product, and the price list information is on columns:

[image]

EXAMPLE DATA:

[image]

A few notes:

I dont know who many price lists i will have, so i could have the column "cost" (for ex) N amount of times.
The product information (first part) needs to be included.
No more than one row per id_Art.

I been working on the following, but i wanted to step back because i might be going into a rabbit hole and there might be an easier solution.

Currently, i'm creating new datatables filtered by each pricelist. The idea behind this was to join the datatables, but i got stucked.

```
     foreach(var pricelist in pricelists)
        {
            DataSet dataSetsingle = new DataSet();                
            dataSetsingle = GetDataSetForMultiTariff(tarifa, dpto, secc, fam, subfam); //This will return a datatable filtered by pricelist
            System.Data.DataTable dtnew = dataSetsingle.Tables[0];

            var results = from table1  in dtinitial.AsEnumerable()
                          join table2 in dtnew.AsEnumerable()
                           on new { A = table1["ID_ART"], B = table1["ID_FORMAT"] } equals new { A = table2["ID_ART"], B = table2["ID_FORMAT"] }
                          select new
                          {
                              table1,table2
                          };



        }
```

1. Should i keep moving forward through this approach? I dont get a flattend result the way i'm doing it, and i'm not sure how to solve that.
2. I have access to the database, so i could potentially change the query.
3. Pivot tables could work?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: In general, using a `DataTable` is not a modern approach, but sometimes it is easiest. Your Example Data seems to have nothing to do with your pictures of PRODUCT/PRICELIST/PRICE - is it right?

Comment: PS Note this is always wasteful: `DataSet dataSetsingle = new DataSet(); dataSetsingle =` : you just created a new `DataSet` and then overwrote it with an assignment, throwing it away. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue with the LINQ `join` over `DataTable`s, this extension method can help, but I think you would be better off with a pivot. Unfortunately I can't tell from your question what you want to pivot, but I do have a pivot method for a `DataTable` as well.

```
public static class DataTableExt {
    // ***
    // *** T Extensions
    // ***
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsSingleton<T>(this T first) {
        yield return first;
    }

    // ***
    // *** MemberInfo Extensions
    // ***
    public static Type GetMemberType(this MemberInfo member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.FieldType;
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.PropertyType;
            case EventInfo mei:
                return mei.EventHandlerType;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be if type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or EventInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }

    public static object GetValue(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) {
        switch (member) {
            case FieldInfo mfi:
                return mfi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case PropertyInfo mpi:
                return mpi.GetValue(srcObject);
            case MethodInfo mi:
                return mi.Invoke(srcObject, null);
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("MemberInfo must be of type FieldInfo, PropertyInfo or MethodInfo", nameof(member));
        }
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(this MemberInfo member, object srcObject) => (T)member.GetValue(srcObject);

    // ***
    // *** Type Extensions
    // ***
    public static List<MemberInfo> GetPropertiesOrFields(this Type t, BindingFlags bf = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) =>
    t.GetMembers(bf).Where(mi => mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field || mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property).ToList();

    // ***
    // *** DataTable Extensions
    // ***
    public static IEnumerable<DataColumn> DataColumns(this DataTable aTable) => aTable.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
    public static IEnumerable<string> ColumnNames(this DataTable aTable) => aTable.DataColumns().Select(dc => dc.ColumnName);

    // Create new DataTable from LINQ join results on DataTable
    // Expect T to be anonymous object of form new { [DataRow or other] d1, [DataRow or other] d2, ... }
    public static DataTable FlattenToDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src) {
        var res = new DataTable();
        if (src.Any()) {
            var firstRow = src.First();
            var memberInfos = typeof(T).GetPropertiesOrFields();
            var allDC = memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => (mi.GetMemberType() == typeof(DataRow)) ? mi.GetValue<DataRow>(firstRow).Table.DataColumns() : new DataColumn(mi.Name, mi.GetMemberType()).AsSingleton());

            foreach (var dc in allDC) {
                var newColumnName = dc.ColumnName;
                if (res.ColumnNames().Contains(newColumnName)) {
                    var suffixNumber = 1;
                    while (res.ColumnNames().Contains($"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}"))
                        ++suffixNumber;
                    newColumnName = $"{newColumnName}.{suffixNumber}";
                }
                res.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(newColumnName, dc.DataType));
            }

            foreach (var objRows in src)
                res.Rows.Add(memberInfos.SelectMany(mi => (mi.GetMemberType() == typeof(DataRow)) ? mi.GetValue<DataRow>(objRows).ItemArray : mi.GetValue(objRows).AsSingleton()).ToArray());
        }
        return res;
    }

}
```

Hmmm... didn't realize how many extension methods that code used :)